# P implies Q logical expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Let the expressions below stand:

H: Student does his homework
P: Student passes the exam
D: Student has dropped the course

How to express P->H ?

It seems like the logical solution would be Student passes the exam is necessary for doing his homework , however not sure if that's correct or not. How would the correct expression look?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the logical solution would be "Student passes the exam is necessary for doing his homework"

No.

The assertion that "$N$ is necessary for $S$" is equivalent to claiming "When $S$ is true, then $N$ must be true", and symbolically represented by $S\to N$.

Here you have $P\to H$, so ...

Comment: So the answer would be Student doing his homework is necessary for him to pass the exam ?

Comment: Indeed so, @NULLPTR